# Multiply an element in a Nested Array by certain value and then add the results together

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to multiply each *"column"* of an array by a *specific number*, and then sum up the results for each *"row"*.

I was able to figure out how to do this for a single array, but I am having trouble figuring this out for a *2d-array*.

I need to do this **recursively**, so no loops. Can anybody provide a pseudocode, or explain what steps I should be taking for each column?

```
public static int didIt(int[] d, int n) {        
    //base or terminating condition
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return didIt(d, n - 1) + d[n - 1] * 10;
    }
    if (n == 2) {
        return didIt(d, n - 1) + d[n - 1] * 50;
    }
    if (n == 3) {
        return didIt(d, n - 1) + d[n - 1] * 22;
    }
    if (n == 4) {
        return didIt(d, n - 1) + d[n - 1] * 7;
    }
    if (n == 5) {
        return didIt(d, n - 1) + d[n - 1] * 45;
    } else {
        return didIt(d, n - 1) + d[n - 1];
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    System.out.println(didIt(array2, array2.length));
}
```

How would I turn this code into a *2d-array* version?

Comment: Multipliers are arbitrary or form an arithmetic progression like it was shown previously?

Comment: And they need to be applied only to the first `5` element in every nested array? I.e. the 6-th, 7-th, etc. elements should be added up as is (without multiplying)?

Comment: And how this logic should be translated into processing a multidimensional array? Do you want every "row" to be processed in the same way or differently?

Comment: Please add clarifications on these points. Try not to avoid overcomplicating things (unless it's a requirement of an assignment), it helps to keep focus on the overall algorithm itself since your purpose is to learn how recursion works.

Comment: okay sorry. each row does the same thing, they add the results. This result is multiplication of each element, in which each column does the same number.
{{(1*10)+(2*20)+(3*30)},
{(4*10)+(5*20)+(6*30)},
{(7*10)+(8*20)+(9*30)}}

Comment: What should happen after the `5`-th element? Its value should be added up as is (without multiplying)?

Comment: Please add this info to the question.

Comment: nothing happens after 5th element because there are only 5 columns, just returns the results

Comment: `there are only 5 columns` - It's **not** a good practice to write the code that is limited in usage without any obvious reason. Why should this method be suitable only for arrays of length `5` or less?

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

Since you need every *"row"* to be treated in the same way you can recursively add up the total calculated for every nested array by moving position in the matrix with every recursive call:

```
public static int arrSum(int[] arr, int pos) {
    if (pos == arr.length) { // base case
        return 0;
    }
    
    return arr[pos] + arrSum(arr, pos + 1); // recursive case
}
```

Your condition logic can be brushed up like that:

```
public static int arrSum(int[] arr, int pos) {

    if (pos == arr.length) { // base case
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (pos == 0) {
        return 10 * arr[pos] + arrSum(arr, pos + 1);
    }
    if (pos == 1) {
        return 50 * arr[pos] + arrSum(arr, pos + 1);
    }
    if (pos == 2) {
        return 22 * arr[pos] + arrSum(arr, pos + 1);
    }
    if (pos == 3) {
        return 7 * arr[pos] + arrSum(arr, pos + 1);
    }
    if (pos == 4) {
        return 45 * arr[pos] + arrSum(arr, pos + 1);
    }
    
    return arr[pos] + arrSum(arr, pos + 1);
}
```

---

###### This part is related to the Initial version of the Question

You don't need redundant conditional logic repeated for every hard-coded value of `n`.

As well as there's no need to multiply each element of the array by `10`, instead we can multiply by `10` the overall sum.

That's how your recursive method that calculates the array sum can be fixed:

```
public static int arrSum(int[] arr, int pos) {
    if (pos == arr.length) { // base case
        return 0;
    }
    
    return arr[pos] + arrSum(arr, pos + 1); // recursive case
}
```

And that how you can calculate the sum of the elements of a nested array (the logic is almost the same):

```
public static int matrixSum(int[][] matrix, int pos) {
    if (pos == matrix.length) { // base case
        return 0;
    }
    
    return arrSum(matrix[pos], 0) + matrixSum(matrix, pos + 1); // recursive case
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    System.out.println(matrixSum(matrix, 0) * 10);
}
```

*Output:*

```
450 // sum of numbers from 1 to 9 equels 45, and * 10 = 450
```

*Sidenote:* in Java there's no *2d-arrays* (so this term isn't correct accurate). We can create a *nested array* - an array that is composed of other arrays.

Comment: Ah i shouldve changed the code a bit, not every n value is multiplied by 10. Some are multiplied by .1 and other values are multiplied by 20. I was just trying to simplify it for my own purposes. My bad.

Comment: @nealgoogs You mean, let's say `z` **first elements** of each nested array should be multiplied by `10`, others by `20`. I understood you correctly?

Comment: Yes, and then within each nested array add the sum of those multiplied results.

Comment: @nealgoogs So, each element in every array need to be multiplied by `10*(index+1)`, right? If yes, then please [add this example to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72754885/edit) so that everyone can see it without reading through these comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use same logic; just change how you can call your `didIt` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = { { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                { 2, 2, 2, 2 },
                { 3, 3, 3, 3 } };
        
        for(int a[]: arr) {
           System.out.print(didIt(a,a.length));
        }
```

No need to change anything in `didIt`.

Also, I assume your `didIt` which you showed here is for demonstraion purpose, otherwise there is plenty of repeated code in `if` which you can able to avoid.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. OP said `need to do this recursively so no loops`

Comment: Loop is not used in actual logic, but used when calling function.  There is no mention of loop should not be used at all anywhere. Actual logic still have no loops

Comment: Well, to begin with, your code doesn't produce the total of the array as required.